# Zeppelin Spark Interpreter (sc.textFile) throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

**Vesions**

Zeppelin version: 0.7-SNAPSHOT version.

Spark 1.6

CDH 5.7.1

Scala 2.10

`sc.textFile` is causing

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;JJZ)V`

```
val dataset=sc.textFile("/tmp/expenses.csv")
dataset.count()
dataset.first()
```

full strack trace

```
dataset: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /tmp/expenses.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:29
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;JJZ)V
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.locatedBlocks2Locations(DFSUtil.java:522)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.locatedBlocks2Locations(DFSUtil.java:486)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$1.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$1.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileBlockLocations(DistributedFileSystem.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileBlockLocations(DistributedFileSystem.java:209)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:343)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that binary compatibility is broken.

I think you should build using the appropriate hadoop profile (CDH 5.7)

- https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/f127237fb1f774d540ce9d8e5885c0dddd35419a/spark/pom.xml#L513-L552

You can refer build profile in this page

- http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/install/build.html#phadoop-version

These are available hadoop profiles in 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT

`-Phadoop-0.23
-Phadoop-1
-Phadoop-2.2
-Phadoop-2.3
-Phadoop-2.4
-Phadoop-2.6`

Comment: Thanks for the "binary compatibility " clue @1ambda. replaced `zeppelin-server/target/lib/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` with `hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.jar` and it is working nicely.